# JAVAFX: How can I put this into one window instead of two?

Tags: javafx

I've been trying to make a toolbar inside a window with a checkers game, what happens now is, Checkers game opening in a separate window and so is the toolbar, what am I doing wrong? How can I make this code open in one window with both functions?

```
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Stage toolStage = new Stage();
    Button btnNewGame = new Button("New Game");
    Button btnConcede = new Button("Concede");
    Button btnNetwork = new Button("Network");

    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
    toolBar.getItems().addAll( new Separator(), btnNewGame, btnConcede, btnNetwork);

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setTop(toolBar);
    Scene toolScene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
    toolStage.setScene(toolScene);
    toolStage.show();

    Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Dam spill - OBJ2000 Eksamen 2016");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `Scene`+`Stage` fot the toolbar, show it and then show the content in the `primaryStage` instead of adding both toolbar and content as parts of the same scene, e.g. by adding the content as `center` node of the `BorderPane`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Button btnNewGame = new Button("New Game");
    Button btnConcede = new Button("Concede");
    Button btnNetwork = new Button("Network");

    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
    toolBar.getItems().addAll( new Separator(), btnNewGame, btnConcede, btnNetwork);

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setTop(toolBar);
    pane.setCenter(createContent());

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Dam spill - OBJ2000 Eksamen 2016");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```